# On edit data from inlineformset_factory is missing

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

This is my code to get recipe data

```
objRecipe = models.Recipe.objects.get(id=recipe_id)
recipe = models.RecipeForm(instance=objRecipe)

objRecipeSteps = models.RecipeStep.objects.filter(recipe__id = objRecipe.id)
recipeSteps = models.RecipeStepFormSet(queryset=objRecipeSteps)
```

I am able to display data from "recipe" but not from "recipeSteps".

This is my template code

```
{{ recipeSteps.management_form }}

    {% for form in recipeSteps.forms %}
      <div class="form-row">
        <span class="label">
          <span class="step-add"><a href="#">Add</a></span>
          <span class="step-remove"><a href="#">Remove</a></span>
        </span>
        {{ form.recipe_step }}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

I couldn't find anything here
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your link explains what to do. Instead of passing a queryset, pass the `instance` parameter, which is the Recipe object.

```
recipeSteps = models.RecipeStepFormSet(instance=objRecipe)
```